# How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?

Tags: php, postman, guzzle

Does anybody know the correct way to `post` JSON using `Guzzle`?

```
$request = $this->client->post(self::URL_REGISTER,array(
                'content-type' => 'application/json'
        ),array(json_encode($_POST)));
```

I get an `internal server error` response from the server. It works using Chrome `Postman`.

Comment: Request seems ok... have you checked the content of $_POST to be sure that you really get the values before encoding them ? : var_dump($_POST)

Comment: According to docs now, you can just use what @davykiash said, `'json' => $data`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154428/842768

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For **Guzzle <= 4**:

It's a raw post request so putting the JSON in the body solved the problem

```
$request = $this->client->post(
    $url,
    [
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ],
);
$request->setBody($data); #set body!
$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: This no longer works with GuzzleHttp. @Charlie has the right answer

Comment: I think we just need to specify the version of Guzzle in the question.

Comment: If you want to set the content type header in Guzzle 6, you can do it like this: `$client->post($url, ['body' => $string, 'headers' => ['Content-type' => 'application/json']]);`

Comment: I have tried this with Guzzle3 is not working even if it is the way mentionned in the doc : https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/request.html?highlight=raw#raw-post-data  , it's been 2 days I am trying to solve this pb but in vain

Comment: According to docs now, you can just use what @davykiash said, `'json' => $data`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154428/842768

Answer (score 346):

For **Guzzle 5, 6 and 7** you do it like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('url', [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['foo' => 'bar'] // or 'json' => [...]
]);
```

[Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json)

Comment: This is the right way to do ([official example here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json))

Comment: According to [doc](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-requests) magic methods can be used. So `post()` should work.

Comment: It's recommended to use `RequestOptions` constants for the options array keys (`GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON` in this case) - it makes typos easier to detect as they suddenly become notices instead of just silent bugs waiting to cause trouble.

Comment: @ksadowski Can you share docs with this info ? In https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/RequestOptions.php#L140 RequestOptions::JSON is a constant with "json" - so it should be the same.

Comment: @MichalGallovic It is the same. The purpose to use the constant is to avoid typos. Using a constant that does not exists will raise an error, but sending a useless option (as `jsson` for example) won't raise any error, and you may take some time to find your typo.

Comment: I was looking around for an hour for this answer. Why is this not in the documentation (especially the quick setup guide)? Crazy!?!

Comment: According to docs now, you can just use what @davykiash said, `'json' => $data`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44154428/842768

Comment: @giovannipds GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON is an alias to 'json', either is fine.

Comment: @Tebe tried with Guzzle ^6.3 and it works with json string as well as constant.

Comment: just replaced library, much less hasssles , recommending this https://github.com/rmccue/Requests   . what e mess it should be  if sending simple post request take s a whole discussion

Comment: When using a client supplied by Google APIs the `'json' => $data` syntax did not work for me. 
 But the `GuzzleHTTP\RequestOptions::JSON` syntax worked as expected.

Comment: how would we handle actual list values in json , in this case

Answer (score 62):

The simple and basic way (guzzle6):

```
$client = new Client([
    'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]
]);

$response = $client->post('http://api.com/CheckItOutNow',
    ['body' => json_encode(
        [
            'hello' => 'World'
        ]
    )]
);
```

To get the response status code and the content of the body I did this:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($response->getStatusCode(), true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($response->getBody()->getContents(), true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: This is really one simple and easy way. Solved my problem about setting body and headers. Thanks very much

Comment: This answer works for me when the accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: I used a variation of this. I created the `Client` by itself and added the headers to the `$client->post()` call instead.

Answer (score 38):

This worked for me (using Guzzle 6)

```
$client = new Client(); 
$result = $client->post('http://api.example.com', [
            'json' => [
                'value_1' => 'number1',
                'Value_group' =>  
                             array("value_2" => "number2",
                                    "value_3" => "number3")
                    ]
                ]);

echo($result->getBody()->getContents());
```

Answer (score 25):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$body['grant_type'] = "client_credentials";
$body['client_id'] = $this->client_id;
$body['client_secret'] = $this->client_secret;

$res = $client->post($url, [ 'body' => json_encode($body) ]);

$code = $res->getStatusCode();
$result = $res->json();
```

Comment: Does this also set the correct header? I think `['json' => $body]` is the better way here, as mentioned by Michael's answer.

Comment: `$res->json();` only works in Guzzle 5.3. It's been removed in v6.

Comment: David is correct. This is because of PSR-7 implementation. Use `json_decode()` instead.

Comment: this will not work when you have to send headers, f.e. authorization tokens for git. you have to instantiate a Request object and use the send or request function

Answer (score 22):

You can either using hardcoded `json` attribute as key, or you can conveniently using `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON` constant.

Here is the example of using hardcoded `json` string.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('url', [
    'json' => ['foo' => 'bar']
]);
```

See [Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).

Answer (score 11):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.com/api']);

$response = $client->post('/save', [
    'json' => [
        'name' => 'John Doe'
    ]
]);

return $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me with Guzzle 6.2 :

```
$gClient =  new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'www.foo.bar']);
$res = $gClient->post('ws/endpoint',
                            array(
                                'headers'=>array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'),
                                'json'=>array('someData'=>'xxxxx','moreData'=>'zzzzzzz')
                                )
                    );
```

According to the documentation guzzle do the json_encode

Answer (score 7):

### Solution for $client->request('POST',...

For those who are using `$client->request` this is how you create a JSON request:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', "https://some-url.com/api", [
    'json' => [
        'paramaterName' => "parameterValue",
        'paramaterName2' => "parameterValue2",
    ]
    'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ]
]);
```

[***Guzzle JSON Request Reference***](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json)

Answer (score 2):

Php Version: 5.6

Symfony version: 2.3

Guzzle: 5.0

I had an experience recently about sending json with Guzzle. I use Symfony 2.3 so my guzzle version can be a little older.

I will also show how to use debug mode and you can see the request before sending it,

When i made the request as shown below got the successfull response;

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,        
        'Accept'        => 'application/json',
        "Content-Type"  => "application/json"
    ];        

    $body = json_encode($requestBody);

    $client = new Client();    

    $client->setDefaultOption('headers', $headers);
    $client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);
    $client->setDefaultOption('debug', true);

    $response = $client->post($endPoint, array('body'=> $body));

    dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3379466 is correct, but here I rewrite in full:

```
-package that you need:

 "require": {
    "php"  : ">=5.3.9",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^3.8"
},

-php code (Digest is a type so pick different type if you need to, i have to include api server for authentication in this paragraph, some does not need to authenticate. If you use json you will need to replace any text 'xml' with 'json' and the data below should be a json string too):

$client = new Client('https://api.yourbaseapiserver.com/incidents.xml', array('version' => 'v1.3', 'request.options' => array('headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/vnd.yourbaseapiserver.v1.1+xml', 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'), 'auth' => array('username@gmail.com', 'password', 'Digest'),)));
```

```html
$url          = "https://api.yourbaseapiserver.com/incidents.xml";
        
$data = '<incident>
<name>Incident Title2a</name>
<priority>Medium</priority>
<requester><email>dsss@mail.ca</email></requester>
<description>description2a</description>
</incident>';
```

```
    $request = $client->post($url, array('content-type' => 'application/xml',));

    $request->setBody($data); #set body! this is body of request object and not a body field in the header section so don't be confused.

    $response = $request->send(); #you must do send() method!
    echo $response->getBody(); #you should see the response body from the server on success
    die;
```

--- Solution for *** Guzzle 6 *** ---
-package that you need:

```
 "require": {
    "php"  : ">=5.5.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
},

$client = new Client([
                             // Base URI is used with relative requests
                             'base_uri' => 'https://api.compay.com/',
                             // You can set any number of default request options.
                             'timeout'  => 3.0,
                             'auth'     => array('you@gmail.ca', 'dsfddfdfpassword', 'Digest'),
                             'headers' => array('Accept'        => 'application/vnd.comay.v1.1+xml',
                                                'Content-Type'  => 'text/xml'),
                         ]);

$url = "https://api.compay.com/cases.xml";
    $data string variable is defined same as above.


    // Provide the body as a string.
    $r = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'body' => $data
    ]);

    echo $r->getBody();
    die;
```

Comment: Thank you. Could not find any guzzle3 solution anywhere else for legacy php5.3 projects, would like to see it line-break'd like your guzzle6 aswell since it would have saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this it will work

```
   $auth = base64_encode('user:'.config('mailchimp.api_key'));
    //API URL
    $urll = "https://".config('mailchimp.data_center').".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches";
    //API authentication Header
    $headers = array(
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$auth
    );
    $client = new Client();
    $req_Memeber = new Request('POST', $urll, $headers, $userlist);
    // promise
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($req_Memeber)->then(function ($res){
            echo "Synched";
        });
      $promise->wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code that works very reliably.

The JSON data is passed in the parameter $request, and the specific request type passed in the variable $searchType.

The code includes a trap to detect and report an unsuccessful or invalid call which will then return false.

If the call is sucessful then json_decode ($result->getBody(), $return=true) returns an array of the results.

```
    public function callAPI($request, $searchType) {
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(["base_uri" => "https://example.com"]);

    try {
        $result = $guzzleClient->post( $searchType, ["json" => $request]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $error .= '<pre>'.print_r($request, $return=true).'</pre>';
        $error .= 'No returnable data';
        Event::logError(__LINE__, __FILE__, $error);
        return false;
    }
    return json_decode($result->getBody(), $return=true);
}
```

Comment: that json option is super handy

Answer (score -1):

The answer from @user3379466 can be made to work by setting `$data` as follows:

```
$data = "{'some_key' : 'some_value'}";
```

What our project needed was to insert a variable into an array inside the json string, which I did as follows (in case this helps anyone):

```
$data = "{\"collection\" : [$existing_variable]}";
```

So with `$existing_variable` being, say, 90210, you get:

```
echo $data;
//{"collection" : [90210]}
```

Also worth noting is that you might want to also set the `'Accept' => 'application/json'` as well in case the endpoint you're hitting cares about that kind of thing.

Comment: Just a heads up... you can simplify your `$data` by using `json_encode`: `$data = json_encode(array('collection' => $existing_variable));`

Answer (score -1):

Above answers did not worked for me somehow. But this works fine for me.

```
 $client = new Client('' . $appUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $appUrl['host'] . '' . $appUrl['path']);

 $request = $client->post($base_url, array('content-type' => 'application/json'), json_encode($appUrl['query']));
```