# Guzzle HTTP client auth fail

Tags: api, authentication, client, authorization, guzzle

I'm working on a project that need to call a API to get json response, but the Guzzle client auth is not working. It always redirect to the login page.
"nasa" is the database.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once '../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client([
    'base_url' => ['http://fedview.bfountain.com/{datasource}/', ['datasource' => 'nasa']]]);
$response = $client->get('service/sbapp/goalByAgency', ['auth' =>  ['username', 'password']]);
echo $response->getBody();
?>
```

I tried:

```
$response = $client->get('login.do?uname=username&passcode=password');
```

It can log in successfully.

Can anyone help me on this? (I'm using Guzzle 5) THX!

Comment: When giving the auth credentials in the get method try without the 'auth' key.  exa: ```$response = $client->get('service/sbapp/goalByAgency', ['username', 'password']);```

Comment: Ohhh. Wait. Using the login.do url works?

Comment: That is NOT basic auth.  Do a get and send with the ```login.do?uname=username&passcode=password``` first then get and send the ```service/sbapp/goalByAgency```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the WHY - logic of what happens I will have to leave the rest of troubleshooting for you.

1) echo $response->getBody(); // prints out the login page "It always redirect to the login page"

2) $response = $client->get('service/sbapp/goalByAgency', ['auth' =>  ['username', 'password']]); // your $response is a login page because you ask $client->get the login page or authenticate page

3) You need to authenticate successfully for a $client
4) Then use the $client to request data via POST method (you missed this step)

see my other post: [How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json)

redo your code. you are on the right track.