# guzzle ver 6 post method is not woking

Tags: php, guzzle

is working in postman (raw format data with with application/json type) 
with guzzle6

```
url-http://vm.xxxxx.com/v1/hirejob/
{
        "company_name":" company_name",
        "last_date_apply":"06/12/2015",
        "rid":"89498"
}
```

so am getting response 201 created
but in guzzle

```
    $client = new Client();
    $data = array();
    $data['company_name'] = "company_name";
    $data['last_date_apply'] = "06/12/2015";
    $data['rid'] = "89498";
    $url='http://vm.xxxxx.com/v1/hirejob/';
    $data=json_encode($data);
    try {
            $request = $client->post($url,array(
                    'content-type' => 'application/json'
            ),array());

        } catch (ServerException $e) {
          //getting GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException Server error: 500
        }
```

i am getting error on `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php`

line no 69

```
 ? new ServerException("Server error: $code", $request, $response)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not actually setting the request body, but arguably the easiest way to transfer JSON data is by using the dedicated request option:

```
$request = $client->post($url, [
    'json' => [
        'company_name' => 'company_name',
        'last_date_apply' => '06/12/2015',
        'rid' => '89498',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: @RahulG There's no mention of that in your question, though.

Comment: @RahulG I've updated my answer; it should work with the latest version of the lib

Comment: thnx jack you saved my time

Answer (score 1):

You need to use json_encode() JSON_FORCE_OBJECT flag as the second argument. Like this:

`$data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Without the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT flag, it will create a json array with bracket notation instead of brace notation.

Also, try sending a request like this:

```
$request = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ],
    'body' => $data
]);
```

Comment: $data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); is not working

Comment: Try this in combination with the answer above.

Comment: You're going to have to set the data to be sent AND it needs to be formatted properly as a JSON object.

Comment: i checked is that is json object

Comment: I just updated my answer. See if that request works for you, now.

Comment: Helped me with my issue. TY