# LARAVEL RESTAPI only working through postman and not with Guzzle

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, laravel-5, jwt, guzzle

Well i have a strange issue, I have 2 instances of laravel5. One works as an api, while the other one works as a frontend website. I am using guzzle 6 (an http client library) on the frontend website for api requests.

I have 2 routes on the api:

1. http://example.dev/api/test (returns 'hello') )
2. http://example.dev/api/authenticate ( returns OAUTH2 or JWT access_token)

**The first route (test) works fine with both postman and GUZZLE and Here is the code. (Note: The form params are not necessary for this route, but i have included to show the difference )**

```
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.dev/api/']);

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'test', [
        'form_params' => [                    // Not necessary
            'username' => 'email@example.com',// Not necessary
            'password' => 'password',         // Not necessary
        ]
    ]);

    $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); 
    dd($result);
```

**The Second Route (authenticate) Works with POSTMAN and we get a token back but not with guzzle.**

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.dev/api/']);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'authenticate', [
    'form_params' => [                    
        'username' => 'email@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',         
    ]
]);

$result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); 
dd($result);
```

The error i recieve on the second route is "ServerException in Middleware.php line 68:". Although no middleware has been assigned to it, Another question also has a very similar problem and they solved it with some modification to the above code.

I have been banging my head for 2 days now, and there are so many different versions of guzzle, and every version has its own code. **I have tried using both OAuth2 & JWT but i think there is some kind of header missing or something.**

It would be really great if you can share the code that works no matter what version of guzzle it is, as i can downgrade it.

Comment: In my current Guzzle6 line 68 of Middleware.php is `ServerException("Server error: $code", $request, $response)`, which should itself be giving an error. Do you know what the actual server error is, whats the response here?

Comment: Well i am sure the error is not from the api. The error is from the used above code. I have removed all the middlewares but its still there. I forgot to add the reference to the other similar questions having the same error with guzzle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860235/guzzle-ver-6-post-method-is-not-woking

Comment: I have also used guzzle 5 but it also has similar errors. Can you post the code that you use to send requests through post? preferably the part where you request the access token.

Comment: Are you able to open a chat? This may be too long for comments

Comment: ya sure, that would be really helpfull :)

Comment: Here is the link to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89805/laravel-rest-guzzle