# Guzzle 6 Post upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, guzzle, guzzle6

I recentely update my guzzle version from 3 to 6.  The following call was working on 3 but now I need to upgrade it to 6 (as it is not working).  After reading the docs, I am a little confused how this new post request works in Guzzle 6.  Here is my OLD post request with Guzzle 3

```
 try
        {
            $request = $this->guzzleClient->post(
                '/login?token='.$this->container->getParameter("token"),
                array(),
                json_encode($data)
            );
            $request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            $response = $request->send();

            return $response->json();
        }
```

How do I transalate that so that it post the request?

Comment: Looks like this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860235/guzzle-ver-6-post-method-is-not-woking

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin - Mark it as a duplicate if the answer on that question applies here as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [guzzle ver 6 post method is not woking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860235/guzzle-ver-6-post-method-is-not-woking)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not really.

Comment: Please give a little more feedback than "not really". If you rewrite your code as the code from the accepted answer, what happens? Error messages? Invalid request?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry about that, nothing, I get no error back.  the post call gets bypassed.

Comment: This PHP code shouldn't be here: `json_encode($data)` maybe you meant `JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
$response = $this->guzzle6->post(
    '/login?token='.$this->container->getParameter("token"),
    [
        'json' => $data
    ]
);

return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Guzzle 6 doesn't have `->json()` for responses, so you have to decode it by yourself.