# how to send data with POST and receive with json in php

Tags: php, json, api, http-post

i want to connect to API.but i need to send data with post, but receive in json.

```
    <?php
$params = array (
'user_name' => '1521',
'user_password' => '8554',
'webservice_user'=>'test',
'token'=>'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70');
$query = http_build_query ($params);
$contextData = array (
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
"Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
'content'=> $query );
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
// Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token;
$result =  file_get_contents (
'IP_ex/login',
false,
$context);
echo($result);
?>
```

when i run my code, receive that Error:

> file_get_contents(url_here): failed to open stream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send json post using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

To receive in in json format, you should do `echo json_encode($myArray)` as

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

if you want to send a post request to a server, you should use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or something similar.

Comment: I will be grateful to give me very simple example

Comment: This one is simple http://stackoverflow.com/a/29601842/1640606 but you have to download the Guzzle library. or this one for curl http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/1640606