# How to execute python script with curl from php?

Tags: php, python, shell, curl

I want to execute python script with post data and get result from there using curl in php. If anyone have done this kind of functionality then please help. I have searched a lot but didn't get anything.

This is my python script path

```
cgi-bin/interactive.py
```

And i want to pass `title=abc` as post data.

I have done it with shell_exec in php file,

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('cgi-bin/interactive.py test');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

But in this i am facing issue with `sys.argv` to fetch argument in python file.

Is it possible to pass argument with key=value with shell_exec? If yes then it can solve my problem otherwise i need to call with curl post data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This one helped me, http://stackoverflow.com/a/43081171/4810125

Answer (score 1):

To do advanced parsing of shell arguments you can use [getopt](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getopt.html) or [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) modules. They are highly configurable and flexible.

Passing post data via shell arguments is, however, not proper as per the [CGI spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451913/how-to-retrieve-form-post-data-via-cgi-bin-program-written-in-c) (if this is supposed to be a true CGI application). Post data comes from `stdin` in CGI, so in your Python program you can read in the HTTP response like regular user input, and then parse out the POST data. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451913/how-to-retrieve-form-post-data-via-cgi-bin-program-written-in-c) for more info.