# Pass array in post request using Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to pass array in post request payload.

```
url = http://IP:PortNo/index.php/v1/login
```

payload:

```
data={ "terminal_id": "terminal_id", "api_login": "api_login", "api_key": "api_key", "merchant_code": "merchant_code" }
```

what i did is:

```
$data = ['terminal_id' => $this->terminal_id , 'api_login' => $this->api_login,
        'api_key' => $this->api_key , 'merchant_code' => $this->merchant_code];
$response = $this->client->post($url, array('data' => $data));
```

but the response i am getting is:

> "Request data not found"

this means my data payload is not correctly formed. any idea?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the $data to json with json_encode? I've done things like `[ 'data' => json_encode($data) ]` in the past with guzzle to have the right body sent.

Comment: yes i didi `j$response = $this->client->post( $url, ['data' => json_encode($data) ] );` but i get the same result `Request data not found`

Comment: Maybe it's in the form of `$this->client->post($url [ 'body' => json_encode([ 'data' => $data ]) ]);` ? Maybe have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json

Answer (score 6):

```
$response = $this->client->post($url, ['json' => $data]);
```

See the Guzzle6 manual in the section entitled json: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json