# How to comunicate with an API with GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to communicate to an API with `laravel` using `guzzleHttp` but I can't receive nothing.

If I test in `postman` returns me information.
In `postman` I set the configuration as you see in image:

In code I'm trying to do that:

```
$token = env('API_TOKEN');
    $company = env('API_COMPANY_ID');
    $link = 'https://xpto.pt/APIs.aspx/Con';

    $data = array('token' => $token, 'empresa' => $company);
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;
    $client = new Client();
    $request = $client->post($link,  ['raw'=>$data]);
    $response = $request->send();

    dd($response);
```

Thank you

Comment: I am also having a problem using guzzleHttp. So I have to use different approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json)