# Guzzle Request : Post body data

Tags: php, request, http-post, guzzle

I'm trying to `POST` data to a remote AWS API.

The data should be a `JSON` on the `body` part.

Using Postman, I can send the data and everything works correctly :

[image]

Now, trying to do so using `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`, I'm doing :

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
            'POST',
            'AWS API URL',
            ['Host' => 'AWS HOST', 'body' => '{"json": "my JSON"}']
        );
$request = $signer->signRequest($request, $credentials);
$response = $client->send($request);
```

The request succeed, but there is no data update ! As if the `'body'` is not received.

I have no access to the remote API log files.

So my question, is this the correct way to post data in body part of a Guzzle request ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json)

Comment: @Jeto, I've edited my question, the `request` should be signed. So I should provide the data on the request object, not on the `client->send()`. At least, that's my analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the linked answer, you need to pass the following options along with your request:

```
[GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'val2']]
```

or:

```
['json' => ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'val2']]
```

But since you need to build your Request object first, you should be able to pass this option as the second parameter of [`Client::send`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L127):

```
$response = $client->send($request, [
  GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'val2']
];
```