# Laravel Send Request to endpoint

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, guzzle, php-curl, guzzle6

These codes throw "Bad Request" error because of parameter. What is the problem of parameter syntax.

```
try{         
    $client = new Client();    
    $response = $client->post("url",
    ['s' => $s, 'p'=> $p]);
    
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
```

Comment: it is just a simple guzzle post request I would suggest to read guzzle docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Guzzle to send a POST request in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244738/how-can-i-use-guzzle-to-send-a-post-request-in-json)

Comment: Unfortunetely still problem is continue @bhucho

Comment: you want to use query parameters? see [this](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Http::post();

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
$response =  Http::post('http://example.com/users',['your data']);
```

Comment: why would you write CURLOPT for things that are already done by guzzle have you tried the code that you have written?

Comment: You are right  I didn't tried the code and it was wrong thank you for your comment