# How to convert PHP cURL format into Guzzle Laravel Format

Tags: php, laravel, curl

currently i'm trying to test some API endpoint use postman. As we know that postman provide us the information to integrate the request into the code in many different languages. So i select code format PHP-cURL on my laravel framework and it works. however i want to convert PHP-cURL format into laravel Guzzle. but didn't work.

here is the PHP-cURL code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.plaid.com/asset_report/create',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
   "client_id": "xxxx",
   "secret": "xxxx",
   "access_tokens": ["access-sandbox-xxx"],
   "days_requested": 30,
   "options": {
      "client_report_id": "ENTER_CLIENT_REPORT_ID_HERE",
      "webhook": "https://www.example.com/webhook",
      "user": {
        "client_user_id": "ENTER_USER_ID_HERE",
        "first_name": "ENTER_FIRST_NAME_HERE",
        "middle_name": "ENTER_MIDDLE_NAME_HERE",
        "last_name": "ENTER_LAST_NAME_HERE",
        "ssn": "111-22-1234",
        "phone_number": "1-415-867-5309",
        "email": "ENTER_EMAIL_HERE"
      }
   }
 }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

this PHP-cURL format can success run and display the response on my laravel. but when i change to Laravel Guzzle.. it display error. here is the guzzle code

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$guzzle = new Client;
$getAccestToken = $guzzle->request('POST', 'https://sandbox.plaid.com/asset_report/create', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'json' => [
                "client_id" => "xxx",
                "secret" => "xxx",
                "access_token" => [ "access-sandbox-xxx" ] ,
                "days_requested" => 30,
                "options" => [
                        "client_report_id" => "ENTER_CLIENT_REPORT_ID_HERE",
                        "webhook" => "https://www.example.com/webhook",
                        "user" => [
                                "client_user_id" => "ENTER_USER_ID_HERE",
                                "first_name" => "ENTER_FIRST_NAME_HERE",
                                "middle_name" => "ENTER_MIDDLE_NAME_HERE",
                                "last_name" => "ENTER_LAST_NAME_HERE",
                                "ssn" => "111-22-1234",
                                "phone_number" => "1-415-867-5309",
                                "email" => "ENTER_EMAIL_HERE"
                            ]
                    ]
                ]   
]);
```

display error

> Client error: `POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/asset_report/create` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "display_message": null, "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-request-errors", "error (truncated...)

What is missing on my guzzle code.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the Http client available which is a wrapper around guzzle:

```
$response = Http::withToken($token)->post('yourUrl', [ params ]);

dd($response->body());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing `json` with `body`:

Also, convert the array into valid JSON format.

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39525059/5192105

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$guzzle = new Client;
$getAccestToken = $guzzle->request('POST', 
'https://sandbox.plaid.com/asset_report/create', [
'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
'body' => json_encode([
            "client_id" => "xxx",
            "secret" => "xxx",
            "access_token" => [ "access-sandbox-xxx" ] ,
            "days_requested" => 30,
            "options" => [
                    "client_report_id" => "ENTER_CLIENT_REPORT_ID_HERE",
                    "webhook" => "https://www.example.com/webhook",
                    "user" => [
                            "client_user_id" => "ENTER_USER_ID_HERE",
                            "first_name" => "ENTER_FIRST_NAME_HERE",
                            "middle_name" => "ENTER_MIDDLE_NAME_HERE",
                            "last_name" => "ENTER_LAST_NAME_HERE",
                            "ssn" => "111-22-1234",
                            "phone_number" => "1-415-867-5309",
                            "email" => "ENTER_EMAIL_HERE"
                        ]
                ]
            ])   
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer. i typo

```
"access_token" => [ "access-sandbox-xxx" ] ,
```

Should with "tokens"

```
"access_tokens" => [ "access-sandbox-xxx" ] ,
```

and it can be run correctly. thank you for all your response.